# NTLM authentication in axis2 client return error 401

Tags: apache-axis

I am using axis2 to create client code and access the wcf webservice with NTLM authentication. My client code is

```
    Service1Stub stub = new Service1Stub();             
    Options options = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();    
    HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator   auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
    auth.setUsername("administrator");
    auth.setPassword("passwrd");
    auth.setHost("172.16.12.25"); 
    auth.setDomain("MY-PC");        
    List<String> authSchemes = new ArrayList<String>();         
    authSchemes.add(HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator.NTLM);        
    auth.setAuthSchemes(authSchemes); 

    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth); 
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE); 
    stub._getServiceClient().setOptions(options);
```

when I run my client code it returns the following error

```
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:310)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at org.tempuri.Service1Stub.welcomeData(Service1Stub.java:473)
        at ws.client.Client.myservice(Client.java:159)
        at ws.client.Client.main(Client.java:50)
```

my header log is

```
     >> "POST /Service1/Service1.svc HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
     >> "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
     >> "SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService1/WelcomeData"[\r][\n]"
     >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
     >> "Content-Length: 278[\r][\n]"
     >> "Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAGMAAAAAAAAAewAAAAkACQBAAAAADQANAEkAAAANAA0AVgAAAAAAAAB7AAAABlIAAFZJTk9USC1QQ0FETUlOSVNUUkFUT1IxNzIuMTYuMTIuMjQ11kmkEIwyUVitHBvTPwhExpcylZ9vkdwd[\r][\n]"
     >> "Host: 172.16.12.25[\r][\n]"
     >> "[\r][\n]"
     >> "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns1:WelcomeData xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><ns1:helloservice>Hello Servie</ns1:helloservice></ns1:WelcomeData></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
     << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
     << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
     << "Content-Type: text/html[\r][\n]"
     << "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5[\r][\n]"
     << "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM[\r][\n]"
     << "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
     << "Date: Thu, 10 May 2012 19:30:20 GMT[\r][\n]"
     << "Content-Length: 1293[\r][\n]"
     << "[\r][\n]"
     << "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">[\r][\n]"
     << "<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">[\r][\n]"
     << "<head>[\r][\n]"
     << "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>[\r][\n]"
     << "<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>[\r][\n]"
     << "<style type="text/css">[\r][\n]"
     << "<!--[\r][\n]"
     << "body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}[\r][\n]"
     << "fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} [\r][\n]"
     << "h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}[\r][\n]"
     << "h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} [\r][\n]"
     << "h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} [\r][\n]"
     << "#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;[\r][\n]"
     << "background-color:#555555;}[\r][\n]"
     << "#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}[\r][\n]"
     << ".content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}[\r][\n]"
     << "-->[\r][\n]"
     << "</style>[\r][\n]"
     << "</head>[\r][\n]"
     << "<body>[\r][\n]"
     << "<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>[\r][\n]"
     << "<div id="content">[\r][\n]"
     << " <div cla"
     << "ss="content-container"><fieldset>[\r][\n]"
     << "  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>[\r][\n]"
     << "  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>[\r][\n]"
     << " </fieldset></div>[\r][\n]"
     << "</div>[\r][\n]"
     << "</body>[\r][\n]"
     << "</html>[\r][\n]
```

I don't know where I made mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the standard release of Axis2 1.6 still uses HTTPClient 3.1 and thus NTLMv1, which most Windows servers have disabled by default. Changing this requires either patching Axis2 or changing the registry settings on the server.

Here's a link to the development thread with a patch as recent as 25-05-2012:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4318

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have figured out a way to access WCF via NTLM authentication.. but this is what I did to fix this issue..

HttpClient doesnt support NTLM v2 hence I use JCIFS library to return NTLM v1,2,3 message type as described in this website

http://devsac.blogspot.com/2010/10/supoprt-for-ntlmv2-with-apache.html

I just used the JCIFS_NTLMScheme.java file from the above website to register the auth scheme and it worked !!!!

Sample client:

```
    List authSchema = new ArrayList();
    AuthPolicy.registerAuthScheme(AuthPolicy.NTLM, org.tempuri.JCIFS_NTLMScheme.class);
    HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
    auth.setUsername("");
    auth.setPassword("");
    auth.setDomain("");
    auth.setHost("");
    auth.setPort();
    List authPrefs = new ArrayList(1);
    authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
    auth.setAuthSchemes(authPrefs);
    stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @WLPhoenix pointed out, Axis2 uses the old Apache Commons HTTP, which only supports an old, reverse-engineered NTLM implementation. In the new Apache HTTPComponents 4.2.3, support was added for the new, openly-documented NTLM standard, which works with newer versions of Windows Server and IIS [(source)](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/ntlm.html).

Here is a way to backport the new Apache HTTPComponents 4 NTLMScheme for use in Axis2 using a custom Apache Commons HTTP AuthScheme.

```java
public class BackportedNTLMScheme extends org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMScheme implements org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthScheme {

    @Override
    public String authenticate(final Credentials credentials, final HttpMethod method) throws AuthenticationException {
        org.apache.commons.httpclient.NTCredentials oldCredentials;
        try {
            oldCredentials = (org.apache.commons.httpclient.NTCredentials) credentials;
        } catch (final ClassCastException e) {
            throw new InvalidCredentialsException(
                    "Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication: " 
                    + credentials.getClass().getName());
        }
        final org.apache.http.auth.Credentials adaptedCredentials = new NTCredentials(oldCredentials.getUserName(), oldCredentials.getPassword(), oldCredentials.getHost(), oldCredentials.getDomain());

        try {
            final Header header = super.authenticate(adaptedCredentials, null);
            return header.getValue();
        } catch (final org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("AuthenticationException", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void processChallenge(final String challenge) throws MalformedChallengeException {
        final String s = AuthChallengeParser.extractScheme(challenge);
        if (!s.equalsIgnoreCase(getSchemeName())) {
            throw new MalformedChallengeException("Invalid NTLM challenge: " + challenge);
        }
        int challengeIdx = challenge.indexOf(' ');
        final CharArrayBuffer challengeBuffer;
        if(challengeIdx != -1){
            challengeBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(challenge.length());
            challengeBuffer.append(challenge);
        } else {
            challengeBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(0);
            challengeIdx = 0;
        }
        try {
            parseChallenge(challengeBuffer, challengeIdx, challengeBuffer.length());
        } catch (final org.apache.http.auth.MalformedChallengeException e) {
            throw new MalformedChallengeException("MalformedChallengeException", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public String getID() {
        throw new RuntimeException("deprecated BackportedNTLMScheme.getID()");
    }


    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public String authenticate(final Credentials credentials, final String method, final String uri) throws AuthenticationException {
        throw new RuntimeException("deprecated BackportedNTLMScheme.authenticate(Credentials, String, String)");
    }
}
```

### Usage

```java
// given a stubbed AXIS SOAP client called MyAxisClient:
MyAxisClientStub myAxisClient = new MyAxisClientStub();
ServiceClient serviceClient = myAxisClient._getServiceClient();

// use new NTLM
AuthPolicy.registerAuthScheme(AuthPolicy.NTLM, BackportedNTLMScheme.class);
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
authenticator.setAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthPolicy.NTLM));
authenticator.setDomain("my-auth-domain");
authenticator.setHost("my-auth-host");
authenticator.setUsername("my-username");
authenticator.setPassword("my-password");
serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, authenticator);

//call MyAxisClient methods
```

I tested this on IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, where should I put this class or how can I integrate Apache HTTPComponents 4 with AXIS? Thanks

Comment: @Haobo I've expanded the Usage section. You can put the class anywhere in your project, as long as your refer to it in `AuthPolicy.registerAuthScheme()` before making SOAP requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried to apply code you posted, the only problem is in "MyAxisClient myAxisClient = new MyAxisClientStub();", eclipse could not resolve MyAxisClientStub, do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I assume that MyAxisClient is your class for AXIS client, tried mine, still could not resolve _getServiceClient()

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `MyAxisClientStub._getServiceClient()` because`_getServiceClient()` is a method on the `Stub` class but the interface hides it. I have updated the Usage.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work until a coworker found this which fixed 401 Unauthorized.

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.CredentialsNotAvailableException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.DefaultHttpParams;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NTCredentials;

final NTCredentials credentials = new NTCredentials(username, password, host, domain);    
final CredentialsProvider myCredentialsProvider = new CredentialsProvider() {
        public Credentials getCredentials(final AuthScheme scheme, final String host, int port, boolean proxy) throws CredentialsNotAvailableException {
            return credentials;
        }
    };

    DefaultHttpParams.getDefaultParams().setParameter("http.authentication.credential-provider", myCredentialsProvider);
```